# External hard drive sounds like it's being scanned constantly

Tags: hard-drive

Recently my external hard drive sounds like it is being constantly scanned or indexed, and I cannot figure out why. I turned off Windows Search and disabled my antivirus software, but it doesn't make any difference. Nothing is being used in the hard drive. I'm using Windows 7. Is there a way to find out what is accessing my hard drive?

Comment: There are lots of programs that do this.  What tools have you used?

Comment: Sounds like Windows being Windows.  But sometimes a drive will play with itself, especially if it's got some bad sectors or some such.

Comment: How much RAM do you have in the computer?

Comment: I have 6GB of RAM

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor your disk activity with Resource Monitor. Simply search `Resource Monitor` in the search bar, or open up your task manager and click the **Resource Monitor** button under the **Performance** tab.

[image]
*Screenshot from http://www.csharpcity.com/2012/simple-strategies-to-boost-sql-server-performance/*

Comment: there is literally nothing showing up for the  drive in question, its all c drive ...

Comment: @Ramhound It does appear to be working with an external drive on my Windows machine, although it's running on Windows 8.

Comment: @JamieSchembri - I suppose I should have been clear, I based my statement, that it wasn't supported based on the user's report it wasn't being listed.  I just confirmed that it works on Windows 7.  Sounds like it not being listed is part of the problem, the disk itself, is likely about to fail.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is a great utility for checking out file access requests. You get an awful lot of information but using filters (highlighted in picture) you can narrow down what's causing the access.

[image: Process Monitor]

Comment: Do all these logged operations actuall touch the physical disk?

Comment: How do you choose a filter/narrowing down? Normally, the output is a very, very long list. How can it be summarised? Is there a statistics function, counting different kinds of accesses from different processes?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No, you need to first limit to something like 'Path' Begins with 'C:\' have a look to see what's happening then further drill down on 'Process' or 'Operation'. If you just want an overview Resource Monitor is better but if you want to know what is actually hitting the disk this is the way to do it.